# GUI for a simple profiler

Tags: c#, java, jfreechart, google-visualization, gantt-chart

Hi I want suggestions on which API to use or tools or any source codes to create a GUI for a simple profiler I have. It produces a text output of the runtime of different processes in a program. I want to show it in a graph format Y axis being the Process name/ids and X axis a timeline. Thus I can show how long it has executed and its start and end point too. Preferably as a normal application and not a web based one. My design has this as a gantt chart with finely grained timeline and support to display 100's of processes on the Y axis (thus a scrollable window )

Comment: You're asking us to design a application for you? And come up with the tools needed to the job? Your need to ask more specific questions here, like "What is a good graph library for a WinForms application? (further requirements like what kind of graphs, if you need mouse interaction with the graph, etc)".

Comment: @Albin I need something like this http://www.jsgantt.com/ except this is a project schedule and its html js based. I am using Fedora.

Comment: @user644575, then click the [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/5228866/edit) link and rephrase your question to ask about a good Gantt-chart for your favorite programming environment.

Comment: @user644575 I removed the javascript, ajax and asp tags. You say explicitly that you don't want a web solution.

Comment: @albin: I said preferably not a web solution. And Yes I will include the gantt chart part

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since this is answerless I'll do what I can. From my experience jfreechart can handle all of the things you described including working as a normal application.

Answer (score 0):

[JGantt](http://www.fileguru.com/JGantt/screenshot) is fairly close to what you seem to be needing.

You could also try [iReport](http://jasperforge.org/projects/ireport) which is an excellent general purpose reporting tool that you can use like a swiss army knife.